# MySQL divide value of two different count statements

Tags: mysql, count

I have the following two MySQL statements which return count results

First statement:

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM sessions ap JOIN session_codes codes USING (code_id) WHERE ap.user=>100 AND (ap.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND codes.status>=1
```

Second Statement:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_sessions FROM sessions WHERE (session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND user=>100
```

Does anyone know a way that I can divide the result of the first statement by the result of the second statement and multiply it by 100 to give me a rounded percentage?

I have just tried the following, and it seems to work, however not sure if this will return the results in the quickest way as it is taking about 0.5 seconds to complete the task:

```
SELECT (
(SELECT count(*) as total FROM sessions ap JOIN session_codes codes USING (code_id) WHERE ap.user=>100 AND (ap.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND codes.status>=1) / 
(SELECT count(*) as total_sessions FROM sessions WHERE (session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND user=>100)
) * 100 AS percentage
```

Comment: That's how you do it. If you're having query performance problems you probably can use an index on the `sessions` table on `session_date`. Read this, especially the section on query performance http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ . Then ask another question focused on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a variable to your `query` result and select it after execution of the query. check this

```
SET @result_1 = (SELECT count(*) as total FROM sessions ap JOIN session_codes codes USING (code_id) WHERE ap.user=>100 AND (ap.session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND codes.status>=1 );

SET @result_2 = (SELECT count(*) as total_sessions FROM sessions WHERE (session_date BETWEEN '2017-01-15' AND '2017-05-10') AND user=>100 );

select (@result_1 / @result_2) * 100
```

Comment: That seems to run much faster than the example I tried above. The example I tried above says the Query took 0.5579 seconds. However, running it using your method returns 3 results and if I add up how long it all took it comes to 0.767 seconds, and definitely feels faster.

Comment: @Ahmed glad to hear that. can you mark it as answer if possible?